# Assigning a nested interface in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to assign a value to a nested interface in typescript but the compiler seems to throw an error even though the format matches correctly

```js
type wheelT = [contemp: number, motemp: number, error: string];

interface getData {
  frontLeft: wheelT[];
  frontRight: wheelT[];
  rearLeft: wheelT[];
  rearRight: wheelT[];
  voltage: number;
  amps: number;
  mode: string;
  FWD: string;
}
```

```js
initjson: getData = {
    frontLeft: [0, 0, "000"],
    frontRight: [0, 0, "000"],
    rearLeft: [0, 0, "000"],
    rearRight: [0, 0, "000"],
    voltage: 0,
    amps: 0,
    mode: "--",
    FWD: "--",
  };
```

essentially throws an error at frontLeft, frontRight, rearLeft, rearRight saying it is not assignable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your type does not match correctly. Your `wheelT` type is a tuple with 3 entries. `frontLeft` (as well as frontRight, rearLeft, rearRight) is of type `wheelT[]` - so an array of tuples. Change this to `wheelT` (without the array brackets) and it should work.

Without the array brackets, `getData` looks like this:

```js
interface getData {
  frontLeft: wheelT
  frontRight: wheelT;
  rearLeft: wheelT;
  rearRight: wheelT;
  voltage: number;
  amps: number;
  mode: string;
  FWD: string;
}
```

Here the [working TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA7gFhCAbAKlAvFA2gYwPYB2wEAtmAFxQECuJARhAE4A0UJexZlN9TrTjPI0oBnYIwCWBAOYBdANwAoRVOKMAZgEMc0aRGAARTcE1QA3oqhR1gogBkI64JXiJUl67eAAlCdLjOsAjIKEpWjBCajA5OLsGoYVARUb7%20ga4hiQBueEgmety0DIyJmmQihbwlHuwAJhCi4lLSiQBiAOoGjZIySgC%20ykj6UFISwABWIoSUeobGppgWVlY2hMAxgVgADKw7UABEW0f7ssweK16pAZTbu6yHx6fnSZHRjpt7ew9bJ2fLLyk-NdsJ97kcfk9-jk8poClAds8ymAKvC-ss6g0DgBaLH7NFWDpdbG4tF9eRAA).